# Optional arguments and func type in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, optional-parameters

I'm trying to realize how to use optional arguments with `feval`.
For instance, if I wrote a function:

```
function [ result ] = foo ( A1, A2 )
if nargin < 2
  A2 = A1;
end
result = A2;
end
```

and used the `func` type to create:

```
func = @(x1,x2) foo(x1, x2);
```

if I try to call `feval` and pass only one of the arguments: `feval(func,x1)`, I get an error message.

How can I still use the defaults when needed with the `func` type?

Comment: Why use an anonymous function and `feval` rather than calling `foo` directly?

Comment: Adding to the comment of @excaza: the problem is not `feval` (besides the fact that you want to use anything with `eval` in it's name: don't do that). Your function `foo` nicely treats  missing input arguments, but an anonymous function `@(x1,x2) ...` will always expect 2 arguments. You *could* do `func = @(varargin) foo(varargin);`, but that will be equivalent to just calling `foo`. *And* you shouldn't call `feval` at all: call your anonymous function with its name, `func(x1)`.

Comment: And you wrote "`func` type" multiple times: there is no `func` type in MATLAB. But this might just be a mental typo:)

Comment: If you insist on using `feval` you can use `func = @foo`, `func = 'foo'` or `func = @(varargin) foo(varargin{:})` instead of `func = @(x1,x2) foo(x1,x2)` which requires 2 input parameters.